# Problem with getting data with Fetch - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, fetch

With the `Postman` program I download my shopping list from https://lit-brushlands-92375.herokuapp.com/api/items with `GET`

I would like to do the same in the browser console or on a website with code:

```
fetch('https://lit-brushlands-92375.herokuapp.com/api/items')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

It returns the following error

> VM89: 1 GET https://lit-brushlands-92375.herokuapp.com/api/items net
> :: ERR_FAILED

**What am I doing wrong? What can be done better?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front-end and Back-end are on Heroku. I received a CORS error. I added the following code to the main file of the back-end layer:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
  
    next();
  });
```

Thanks to this, I obtained a satisfactory effect in the form of downloaded data.

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('https://lit-brushlands-92375.herokuapp.com/api/items')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

worked for me just fine! If you'd prefer it cleaner, there's writing it this way.

```
fetch('https://lit-brushlands-92375.herokuapp.com/api/items').then((response)=>response.json()).then((data) =>console.log(data));
```

Comment: Maybe you fixed it, but no issues?